# How do I prove that $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{Tr}}\tr(A \sqrt{B} A \sqrt{B}) = \tr\Big[\Big(\sqrt{\sqrt{B}} A \sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\Big)^2\Big]$?

Tags: mathematics, density-matrix, trace-distance

Let's say I have 2 density operators $A$ and $B$. Now, here is what I am trying to calculate:
$$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{trace}}
\tr(A \sqrt{B} A \sqrt{B}).
$$
I saw that this trace can be rewritten as:
$$
\tr(A \sqrt{B} A \sqrt{B}) = \tr\Bigg(\Big(\sqrt{\sqrt{B}} A \sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\Big)^2\Bigg).
$$

I was wondering, which property of trace is being used here. I do not think the cyclic property would help, would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the cyclicity of trace.

\begin{align}
\text{tr}\left(\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}A\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\right)^2\right) &= 
\text{tr}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}A\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}A\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\right)\\
&= \text{tr}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}A\sqrt{B}A\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\right)\\
&= \text{tr}\left(A\sqrt{B}A\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\sqrt{\sqrt{B}}\right)\\
&= \text{tr}\left(A\sqrt{B}A\sqrt{B}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: nice! I missed the idea...